# Off Centre Square Geometry Problem

Tags: geometry, word-problem

Square ABCD has side length of 10 cm. The square is placed over a circle, but done so it is off-center. It is offset in such a  way that A and D are on the circle and side BC is tangent to the circle at point P (which is exactly half way down  side BC). Determine the radius of the circle.

Comment: If you have drawn the diagram, you may have come to some conclusions.

Comment: Well, that's easy (6.25 cm), but what's your problem with it?

Comment: *Help us help you* by providing your thoughts on the problem, and a sense of where you got stuck. What tools are available to you? (Are you familiar with the Power of a Point, and/or the Inscribed Angle Theorem? Do you want a coordinate-based proof?) Providing as much context as possible lets us tailor answers to suit you better without wasting time telling you things you might already know. Without context, it may *appear* that you're just asking us to do your homework for you, which would be unfortunate.

Comment: @Blue That's overkill, I'd say. Using just similar triangles, one can do it with a mental calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the midpoint of $\overline{AD}$ by $Q$, the centre of the circle by $O$, and the radius of the circle by $r$. Using the Pythagorean theorem,
$$
\begin{align}
5^2+(10-r)^2&=r^2\\
25+100-20r+r^2&=r^2\\
20r&=125\\
r&=6.25.\\
\end{align}
$$